# Unchecked overriding (well, I seem to need my generics method)

Tags: java, generics

I've got generic interface Operand:

```
public interface Operand<T extends Operand<T>> {
    T add(Operand<T> op);
    T sub(Operand<T> op);
    T mul(Operand<T> op);
    T div(Operand<T> op);
}
```

which is implemented by 2 classes:

```
public class DoubleOperand implements Operand<DoubleOperand> {
    ...
}

public class RationalOperand implements Operand<RationalOperand> {
    ...
}
```

I've written "factory" interface implemented by ***DoubleOperandFactory*** and ***RationalOperandFactory*** classes:

```
public interface OperandFactory {
    <T extends Operand<T>> Operand<T> valueOf(String s);
}

public class DoubleOperandFactory implements OperandFactory{
    @Override
    public Operand<DoubleOperand> valueOf(String s) { ... }
}

public class RationalOperandFactory implements OperandFactory {
    @Override
    public Operand<RationalOperand> valueOf(String s) { ... }
}
```

In my program I use an enum which objects store instance of the particular Factory:

```
public enum OperandType {
    DOUBLE(new DoubleOperandFactory()), RATIONAL(new RationalOperandFactory());
    private OperandFactory fact;
    OperandType(OperandFactory fact){ this.fact = fact; }
    public OperandFactory getFact() { return fact; }
}
```

Now I'm getting message warning "Unchecked overriding" on both factory classes, due to unchecked conversion and I'm pretty confused about this. First thing which I tried is (as it was most commonly answered here in similar topics) to replace generic method with generic factory interface, but finally it turns into impossibility to use them with the enum which should return particular factory, without <?>, as I have to create a List of operands (of generic type T extends Operand<T> for now)  and fill it with the objects produced by selected factory. What would be the best way to reorganize this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface OperandFactory {
    <T extends Operand<T>> Operand<T> valueOf(String s);
}
```

This interface does not do what you think it does.

This interface advertises that an instance of it can generate *any* type of operand you want.  It doesn't just generate one particular kind of operand.  It generates all of them.

This is not what you actually have.

What you need instead is

```
 public interface OperandFactory<T extends Operand<T>> {
    T valueOf(String s);   
 }
```

...and then to give up on the enum, because you can't have enums that have different types in them like that.  That's just not a thing you're allowed to do in Java.

Comment: Then what would be the proper way to use a kind of "selector" in my program to choose a particular factory ?

Comment: Switch on a String, say, pick the OperandFactory explicitly, and pass it from there to something accepting an `OperandFactory` of some specific type `T`.  Or store it in an `OperandFactory<?>` variable.